# Will I be negatively treated based on fake kicks?

Tags: discussion, chat, moderator-tools

A few months ago I and HyperNeutrino decided to bug test kicking and moving messages. In the end we figured out that if you are kicked from a room YOU cannot move your own messages to that room but others can. However you can move other peoples messages to the room you are kicked from (I think that is the right results). We did have a mod on duty if we accidentally triggered an auto flag (I think one was triggered but it was dismissed before anyone else saw it). I couldn't make rooms after that due to kicking (I found that out later), I asked Dennis to fix it which he did (since it was a false alarm auto-ban).

Will I be negatively effected  in the future with potential moderator actions by what we did?

Comment: We tried to stop before the 30 min kick came in and in the end only one 30 min kick was in place. Also both rooms we got nuked by a mod

Comment: If a mod comes asking, just explain the situation. You better make sure it's true or you might be in trouble.

Comment: @AnthonyPham I do have a a mod on hand who can explain what we did. And will verify what I say is true

Answer (score 9):

The only automatic restriction is the one that prevents you from creating new rooms, which kicks in when a mod flag is raised.

Assuming that restriction is lifted, you're clear for the future as far as the system is concerned.

Comment: But no mark in user's history?

Comment: @Sha - yes, it is visible in the history if you can manage to find that page (I don't think it's linked anywhere), if I'm remembering correctly.

Comment: It's under a link named "permissions" in the chat mod tools, @Mithrandir. Nobody ever looks there unless they're trying to figure out why someone can't create chatrooms, so...

Comment: @Shog9 thanks I just wanted to make sure that i wouldn't have a major black mark against me